# All Embedded YouTube Videos Start Playing At Once

Tags: asp.net, youtube, youtube-api, embed

I've got a site which works pretty nicely for the most part.  It's written in ASP.NET, and it renders a GridView, with a row for each video, showing a thumbnail and the description.  Also in each row is a Panel containing the embedded video itself, associated with a ModalPopupExtender so that the Panel (and thus the video) is only made visible when a button, also rendered in each row of the GridView, is pressed.  So far so good.

This works great in IE10.  I've even got some JavaScript which stops the video when the Panel is closed, successfully identifying WHICH embedded video the stop command should be passed to.  HOWEVER, in Google Chrome things don't work as smoothly.

In Chrome, the pages takes a long time to load - the first sign of trouble.  Then, when I click a button to start playing a video, even though only the requested video is made visible, ALL the videos start to play (you can hear the audio from all of them).  This quickly causes Shockwave to crash.

Why should this work in IE10 and not Chrome?  And why does every video start to play just because one does?  I expect I could overcome the problem by not including the `autostart=true` parameter, but I want the videos to autostart when they popup, and it works in IE - as I'd expect them too, since they're each rendered as different embedded videos.

Comment: Missing from your question: the URL of a page demonstrating the problem, so that we could accurately diagnose what's going on and provide advice.

Answer (score 0):

These days, the parameter is `autoplay=0` or `1`. If 0, the video will not auto start. If 1, it will. Default is 0.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autoplay